# How to handle IPC with large (>10MB) pieces of data? -- Node.js (v4.5.0)

Tags: node.js, fork, ipc, child-process

I am currently trying to offload a very CPU-intensive task to a child-process in order to stop my main thread from blocking. The main process generates the data and is being passed via `ChildProcess.send()`. The problem is sometimes this data can range from **10MB - 160MB** large.

**EDIT @ 4:25 01/03/2017**

User `robertklep` recommended I write to a temporary file and pass the filename to the child process. This sped up the process quite a bit, but writing the temporary file - `fs.writeFile` is blocking my server for a few seconds.

Here is what I have currently implemented:

**Parent Process**

```
// Fork process so child will execute compiling code
var child = cp.fork(`${__dirname}/../forkedProcess/compile-csv.js`);

// ===========================
// == Create temporary file ==
// ===========================
var fileName = `./tempFile_${Date.now()}`;
_createTemporaryFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(parsedCSVData, null, 4))
.then(function() {
    try {
        // Send filename to child process once file is created and filled with data
        console.log('Sending filename to child process');
        child.send(fileName);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        reject(new Error(e));
    }
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log('_compileInChildProcess - File creation failed: ' + err);
});
```

**Temporary File Creation**

```
var _createTemporaryFile = function(filePath, data) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log('Creating temporary file...');
        fs.writeFile(filePath, data, 'utf-8', function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('Failed to created temporary file.');
                reject(new Error(err));
            } else {
                console.log('Temp filed created.');
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**Child Process**

```
process.on('message', function(data) {

    if(data === 'mem_usage') { // Debugging purposes ... returns process memory
        process.send({memUsage: process.memoryUsage()});
    } else {
        console.log('Child received data ... ' + data);
        _readFile(data).then(function(jsonObject) {
            csvParser.compileData(jsonObject) // CPU-intensive task
            .then(function(result) {
                console.log('Sending data back to parent ...');
                process.send(result);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                process.send(null);
            });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('_readFile() failed in child process.');
            process.send(null);
        });  
    } // end of else
});

// Implement promises for this asynchronous operation
var _readFile = function(fileName) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('Failed to read file in child process.');
                reject(new Error(err));
            } else {
                console.log('Successfully received data from file in child process.');
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                resolve(obj);
            }
        });
    }); 
};
```

I've discovered a few things after (roughly) profiling these operations:

- The child process takes up 22MB in memory
- If the data is 10-15MB it takes around 2-3 minutes to pass from parent to child
- If the data is around 100MB, it takes A LONG time (30+ minutes)

After the update I have one more problem:

- Creating the temporary file in the parent process seems to cause blocking issues with my server.

Am I executing this process incorrectly?

Comment: Here's a related issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3145 From what I understand, it should be fixed in recent Node v7, but not sure if the fix applies, and will get backported to, older versions (I can reproduce the slowness with v6). Perhaps you should consider an alternative, like using temporary files and passing just their filenames between parent and child.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for the fast response. I'm happy to see it's being worked on in later versions, but I'll have to stick with 4.5 for now. I tried your temporary file solution and that sped up the process quite a bit. But writing to the temporary file seems to be blocking my server ... I've updated my answer to show how I've implemented this.

Comment: Your code hasn't been updated, FYI.

Comment: Whoops @idbehold it should be now.

Comment: I've been through with such experience, node is not the best option to take when it comes to heavy file operations, I suggest to write another script, maybe python, and fire it from node

Comment: For larger files like that or for large data sets, its preferred to make use of streams so that you can process in chunks.

Comment: Also, 100MB isn't very big unless you're running on a really low powered machine.  I suspect there's something else you're doing wrong, can you link to your full repository?  I will also point out that there are pretty massive performance differences between the different flow control options. While many folks find Promises useful for code maintenance, they are not the most high performing option in many cases and depending on which implementation they can be pretty awful.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the response. I'm not too overly concerned about speed (5-8 minutes for a 150-200MB dataset is acceptable) - although I am curious how this could be done faster. Unfortunately I can't link to the repository. I'll dig deeper into streams and see if that will help speed up this process.

Comment: You should also be writing the parsed CSV result back to a temporary file from the child process. The only messages that should be passed between parent and child are file paths.

Comment: As far as transferring data goes, you could avoid the IPC mechanism (and writing to a temporary file) altogether by passing the large data over an extra file descriptor between the parent and child processes. However, if your large data is JSON, it will still take a fair amount of time to parse all of that. If you are in control of the data format, you might simplify it a bit to make parsing faster.

Comment: @PantsMagee when writing files, make sure not to use the `*Sync()` functions, as those will block your process.